# Is there a way to negate constrains?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

How does one implement `NOT` such that `fn` accepts `Y` but not `X`, without creating multiple concepts and chaining them?

```cpp
template<class T>
concept Fooable = requires(T t) {
    { t.foo() };
    NOT({ t.bar()}); // imaginary syntax
};

struct Y {
    void foo() {}
};

struct X {
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};


template <Fooable T>
void fn(T t) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NOT with the `requires`-clause as it yields a `bool`:

```
template<class T>
concept Fooable = requires(T t) {
    t.foo();
    requires (!requires { t.bar(); });
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T59fd8vE8)